# Is it possible to scale up/down Aurora RDS Cluster without downtime?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have RDS Aurora PostgreSQL cluster with two instances:

```
cluster
├── instance_1 [writer] [no multiAZ]
└── instance_2 [reader] [no multiAZ]
```

When I changing instance type for `instance_1` failover operation working correct but I have downtime about 1~2 minutes. I checked downtime by running

```
watch -n 3 "psql -h db.cluster.url -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -c 'select ID from TABLE limit 1'"
```

After that `instance_1` becomes `reader`.

Is there any way to change `instance_1` to reader manually, change it type and revert to writer without long downtime (no downtime is the best, but 5~10 seconds also acceptable)

I know that I may use multiAZ instances but it will be cost twice expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Using [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/de/rds/proxy/) can greatly reduce downtime during failover:

> With RDS Proxy, failover times for Aurora and RDS databases are reduced by up to 66%

A big amount of the seemingly long failover is taken by

1. the client library recovering from a connection loss and
2. the DNS propagation of the reader/writer switch

RDS Proxy handles the reader/writer switch so that no DNS changes have to be propagated to the client, it uses always the same end point.

There is a [good article](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/database/improving-application-availability-with-amazon-rds-proxy/) which shows the speedup from 24 to 3 seconds average failover recovery time when using RDS proxy.

Comment: Hmm... using of related services is not an answer that I expected, but that is really good workaround (and looks like here is no solution without workarounds). Thank you for the hint.